# Jenkins fetching wrong branch when webhook triggers

Tags: git, github, jenkins, gitlab

When gitlab `feature-0` has a commit and it triggers jenkins webhook, jenkins pulls from Main branch instead of `feature-0` branch. Vice versa if `main` branch has a commit, jenkins sometimes fetches from `feature-0` branch. How can I ensure it fetches the right branch when webhook triggers?

```
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
skipping resolution of commit remotes/origin/feature-0, since it originates from another repository
Multiple candidate revisions
Checking out Revision 1cda3cd8cb747c8588daaf07715499ea37927d8b (origin/main)
Commit message: "Please retry a full pipeline [ci build]"
```

The above commit message is from `main` branch. `feature-0` branch has a different commit message and it triggered the jenkins job.

I've specified main and feature in the branches section. But it isn't working as expected.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you use the variable `$GIT_BRANCH` rather than hardcoding the branch to build? (I'm not sure of the name of the variable, it's provided when git hook calls Jenkins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it:

I had to change the branch name to `${gitlabSourceBranch}` in Jenkins and also remove `branch` names when running git checkout in pipeline. Then it started checking out the source branch that triggered the webhook.

[image]

Comment: you r a live safer!